# Google webmaster tool "Severe health issues are found on your site"

Tags: magento, robots.txt, google-search-console

I just saw the " Severe health issues are found on your site. Is robots.txt blocking important pages? "

This is what I have in robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /*?p=
Allow: /index.php/blog/
Allow: /catalog/seo_sitemap/category/
Allow: /catalogsearch/result/
Allow: /media/
Disallow: /404/
Disallow: /app/
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /downloader/
Disallow: /errors/
Disallow: /includes/
Disallow: /js/
Disallow: /lib/
Disallow: /magento/
Disallow: /pkginfo/
Disallow: /report/
Disallow: /scripts/
Disallow: /shell/
Disallow: /skin/
Disallow: /stats/
Disallow: /var/
Disallow: /contents/
Disallow: /contents/fr/
Disallow: /index.php/
Disallow: /catalog/product_compare/
Disallow: /catalog/category/view/
Disallow: /catalog/product/view/
Disallow: /catalogsearch/
Disallow: /checkout/
Disallow: /control/
Disallow: /contacts/
Disallow: /customer/
Disallow: /customize/
Disallow: /newsletter/
Disallow: /poll/
Disallow: /review/
Disallow: /sendfriend/
Disallow: /tag/
Disallow: /wishlist/
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /cron.php
Disallow: /cron.sh
Disallow: /error_log
Disallow: /install.php
Disallow: /LICENSE.html
Disallow: /LICENSE.txt
Disallow: /LICENSE_AFL.txt
Disallow: /STATUS.txt
Disallow: /*.js$
Disallow: /*.css$
Disallow: /*.php$
Disallow: /*?p=*&
Disallow: /*?SID= 
Disallow: /*?limit=all
```

I copied this robots from Magento default robots.txt and I add some folders that I don't need to get it indexed.

Thanks

Comment: This probably belongs in http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't ship with a default `robots.txt`.  The folks over on [Webmasters StackExchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)  can probably better tell you what Google thinks you're blocking important page, but blocking this

```
/catalog/seo_sitemap/category/
```

— A URL setup specifically for SEO, seems a little bananas.